# What is the word for something that shines in the darkness and is dark in the light?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know if there is a word for something that shines in the darkness and is dark in the light (e.g. during the day).

This is specifically for a story I am writing, where I would like to use it to describe two things:

- The material of a weapon; and
- The wings of Nephalem (an angel-demon hybrid).

Comment: If something is mildly luminous, you can generally see it shining in the dark, but  not in daylight.

Comment: I think @MichaelHarvey 's suggestion of "luminous" should work. You will need some surrounding text - "The [hero's] luminous [unobtanium] sword glowed faintly in the gloom" with a similar sentence for the wings.

Comment: Noctilucent might work, although it is mainly applied to clouds in the sky.

Answer (score 1):

Scientifically, all light must have some kind of energy source.

Materials that absorb light during the day and emit it in the dark could be **photoluminescent**.

**Luminescent** means that something spontaneously emits light, usually generating the energy from some biological, chemical reaction.